# When to commit NHibernate transactions and send email in ASP.NET MVC 2 application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, fluent-nhibernate

Similar to [a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3576866/when-to-commit-nhibernate-transactions-in-asp-net-mvc-2-application) I'm struggling with committing transactions and handling exceptions. However, unlike the solution presented there, I would like to solve it using an actionfilter.
Currently I have code in an ActionFilter which looks like this:

```
public override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
{
        base.OnResultExecuted(filterContext);

        // Errors == ROLLBACK UoW
        // No Errors == COMMIT UoW
        if (UnitOfWork != null)
        {
            if (filterContext.Exception == null || filterContext.ExceptionHandled == true)
            {
                try
                {
                    UnitOfWork.Commit();
                    log.Debug("Transaction committed");
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    UnitOfWork.Rollback();
                    log.Error("Transaction rolled back: " + e.Message + (e.InnerException != null ? "" : "; " + e.InnerException.Message), e);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                UnitOfWork.Rollback();
                log.Warn("Transaction rolled back: " + filterContext.Exception.Message + (filterContext.Exception.InnerException == null ? "" : "; " + filterContext.Exception.InnerException.Message), filterContext.Exception);
            }
        }

    }
```

This basically works. However, when an exception does occur, I cannot inform the user of the rollback. Would it also be valid to do the commit in OnResultExecuting? How can I inform the user a rollback was done?
Second, upon a successful commit, sometimes emails need to be sent. How can I get a list of emails to be sent to the ActionFilter?

Comment: Personally I'm leaning towards implementing OnActionExecuted instead of OnResultExecuted. I could provide a list with emails to be sent via the ViewData. It would hardly change the code, but is it a valid solution? What happens with exceptions in OnResultExecuted (what kind of errors happen in this stage?)

Comment: Ok, I think committing OnActionExecuted is a valid way of committing transactions. Of course, I need to notify the user of the rollback, so I probably should load an Error View in filterContext.Result. And for the emails: I could fill HttpContext.Current.Items with a queue of emails to be send and send them upon succesfully committing the transaction and clear the queue. What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
public override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
{
    base.OnResultExecuted(filterContext);
    bool success = true;

    // Errors == ROLLBACK UoW
    // No Errors == COMMIT UoW
    if (UnitOfWork != null)
    {
        if (filterContext.Exception == null || filterContext.ExceptionHandled == true)
        {
            try
            {
                UnitOfWork.Commit();
                log.Debug("Transaction committed");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                UnitOfWork.Rollback();
                log.Error("Transaction rolled back: " + e.Message + (e.InnerException != null ? "" : "; " + e.InnerException.Message), e);
                success = false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            UnitOfWork.Rollback();
            log.Warn("Transaction rolled back: " + filterContext.Exception.Message + (filterContext.Exception.InnerException == null ? "" : "; " + filterContext.Exception.InnerException.Message), filterContext.Exception);
            success = false;
        }
    }

    if (!success)
    {
        // Send Email notifying the user of the problem.
    }

}
```

Comment: That's not exactly what I meant. Emails are generated during the execution of an action, but should not be sent until it has been successfully committed. So I somehow need to defer sending the emails until this is the case. I have decided to use HttpContext.Current.Items for this and it seems to be working.